# Can you forward TLS connections according to SNI domain without terminating the connection at the reverse proxy?

Tags: tls, http, proxy

I am developing an application that needs to expose two services:

- REST API with https and client certificate authentication (https://api.device.example.org:4431, server certificate issued by private CA)
- Web server with regular https (https://device.example.org:4432, server certificate issued by public CA)

I would like to place a reverse proxy in front of these on port 443 that reads the SNI domain and forwards requests to the relevant port.

Is this possible without terminating the TLS connection at the proxy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to do forwarding inside some proxy just based on the SNI extension in the ClientHello and without terminating SSL at the proxy. It is for example [supported by haproxy](https://scriptthe.net/2015/02/08/pass-through-ssl-with-haproxy/) or [sniproxy](https://github.com/dlundquist/sniproxy). See also [Can a Reverse Proxy use SNI with SSL pass through?](https://serverfault.com/questions/625362/can-a-reverse-proxy-use-sni-with-ssl-pass-through).